# Yammer conversation web part in SharePoint online not displaying images in chrome browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, image, yammer

Conversation images not displaying in SharePoint Online "Yammer conversation web part" when using Chrome browser but displaying correctly in Edge.

[image]

When user click 'View all in Yammer' they get redirected to Yammer and the images are displayed correctly on the screen using Chrome or Edge.

Images are JPG format. All images are stored in "Files" tab on Yammer.

Also images in thumbnail are blurry in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in Google Browser, but everything's fine and I can't reproduce your problem.

[image]

What is your Google Chrome version? Try upgrading it to the latest version.

[image]

In addition, the phenomenon of image blur seems to be widespread, I can see that many users are facing the same problem.

The image I uploaded was also vague.

In this regard I suggest you create service request s to contact Office 365 support:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/

Comment: I am using the same version of Google Chrome as yours.

Comment: Is this still the case after re-creation?

Comment: Yes it is still the case.

Comment: I suggest you create service request s to contact Office 365 support

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Yammer issue** you can find this issue here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/yammer/picture-in-conversations-yammer-webpart-showing-blurry/m-p/864106
Even submit a technical support case can't resolve the case, unfortunately Microsoft doesn't have a good support in Yammer